# Page Jumps After Ajax content is loaded

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying load content via ajax when an `<a>` is clicked. The code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // ajax pagination
    jQuery('.znn_paginate a').live('click', function(){
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('.lay1').html('<div class="zn_ajaxwrap"><div class="zn_ajax"></div></div>');
        jQuery('.lay1').fadeOut("slow").load(link+' .post').fadeIn('slow'); 

    }); 
}); // end ready function
</script>
```

**The problem** is When the content is loaded the page jumps to the top. I treid to prevent it with: `e.preventDefault();` But then the the ajax loading stopped. I guess it stopped prevented the ajax loading too..

Is there any fix for this? 
Thanks

P.S: I am using it on wordpress. Here is the tutorial I followed: http://seonix.org/wordpress-seo/easy-ajax-pagination/

**EDIT**

---

There was something wrong with the code. I am now using this without any problem: http://pastebin.com/vbXqmTHq

Answer (score 1):

two things:

your function() should return false.

also the link itself should have href="javascript:void(0);

Comment: The `<a>` tags has links attached to them and its auto generated: `<a class="amp_page" href="http://localhost/wordpress/">1</a>` and when I added return false the ajax loading doesn't work.

Comment: can you paste your new function with the return false in it?  or indicate where you put it in your function?

Comment: I was testing on my local server. for the fast load it was hard to tell whether the ajax was really working or not. I tried to upload my theme on a web server and looks like the ajax load is not working. Here is the link(you can find the code in the header area): http://tritonlite.towfiqi.com/test/  -thanks

Comment: it appears to be working for me, but it does jump to the top of the page.  so, where did you put the return false?

Comment: There was something wrong with that code. I am using this now and its working fine. without any page load and jumping: http://pastebin.com/vbXqmTHq Thanks for your effort.